# How to modify the Ford-Fulkerson maximum flow algorithm to print the visited nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, ford-fulkerson

I need to modify the maximum flow algorithm so that I can view the path related to the maximum flow. No need of printing all the nodes related to the graph I want to print the path for the maximum flow of the graph with the respective capacity.

E.g:-  It should look like this,

**

```
0-1 = capacity1
1-3 = capacity2
3-5 = capacity3
```

**
So by adding the capacities can verify the maximum flow also as both values are same.

Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

public class MaxFlow_Ford_Fulkerson {

```
static class Graph {
int vertices;
int graph[][];

public Graph(int vertex, int[][] graph) {
    this.vertices = vertex;
    this.graph = graph;
}

public int findMaxFlow(int source, int sink) {

    int[][] residualGraph = new int[vertices][vertices];


    for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <vertices ; j++) {
            residualGraph[i][j] = graph[i][j];
        }
    }


    int [] parent = new int[vertices];

    int max_flow = 0; 

    while(isPathExist_BFS(residualGraph, source, sink, parent)){
        int flow_capacity = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        int t = sink;
        while(t!=source){
            int s = parent[t];
            flow_capacity = Math.min(flow_capacity, residualGraph[s][t]);
            t = s;
        }

        t = sink;
        while(t!=source){
            int s = parent[t];
            residualGraph[s][t]-=flow_capacity;
            residualGraph[t][s]+=flow_capacity;
            t = s;
        }

        max_flow+=flow_capacity;
    }
    return max_flow;
}

public boolean isPathExist_BFS(int [][] residualGraph, int src, int dest, int [] parent){
    boolean pathFound = false;

    boolean [] visited = new boolean[vertices];

    Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    queue.add(src);
    parent[src] = -1;
    visited[src] = true;

    while(queue.isEmpty()==false){
        int u = queue.poll();

        for (int v = 0; v <vertices ; v++) {
            if(visited[v]==false && residualGraph[u][v]>0) {
                queue.add(v);
                parent[v] = u;
                visited[v] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    pathFound = visited[dest];
    return pathFound;
}}*
```

**
*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int vertices = 6;
    int graph[][] = { {0, 10, 8, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0},
            {0, 4, 0, 0, 10, 0},
            {0, 0, 9, 0, 10, 3},
            {0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 14},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
    Graph g = new Graph(vertices, graph);
    int source = 0;
    int destination = 5;
    int max_flow = g.findMaxFlow(source,destination);
    System.out.println("Maximum flow : " max_flow); }}
```

*
**

Comment: After visited[v] = true, System.out.print(b)

Comment: it prints all the nodes I want the path related to the maximum flow